# Filtering Matrix blocks

Tags: matrix, filter

I am trying to filter an entry's matrix blocks to just the ones with either operational **OR** hazardous checked (lightswitch). I can chain it together with one, how do you grab items with *either* checked? See the end of the following line.

```
{% set filteredComponents = entry.propertyComponents.relatedTo(category).status('live').order('componentName asc').operational('= 1') %}
```

Comment: I asked a very similar question already [Query for blocks across Block Types using the new field parameter?](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/5056/125) – hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, that did lead me to a solution. To merge I had to add find() so they were arrays.
    {% set filteredComps = asset.assetComponents.relatedTo(category).status('live').order('componentName asc').operational('= 1').find() 
    | merge( asset.assetComponents.relatedTo(category).status('live').order('componentName asc').hazardous('= 1').find() ) %}